# Is there a way to determine if Convert.ToDateTime added the year?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a large collection of text files that need to be parsed using Regexes.  Some of the data that I'm collecting are dates that come in all sorts of formats, such as 12/1/15, Dec 1, 2015, 12-1-15, etc.  They sometimes have a year listed and sometimes don't.  My problem occurs when I have dates that span two years, i.e. 12/1 - 1/8, where the first date needs the year 2015 and the second date needs the year 2016.  Currently I'm parsing them as strings and trying to convert them to DateTimes. This adds the current day's year, so if it's parsed in 2015, the second date is wrong and if it's parsed in 2016 the first date is wrong.  Is there a way to determine when Convert.ToDateTime adds the year since the string was missing one?  If I could determine this I have a way to determine which year needs to be added.

Comment: Why your `12/1` should be `2016` but `1/8` should be `2015`? Or do you have a string like `"12/1 - 1/8"`? What is your parsing pattern _exactly_? A few example inputs and outputs would be fine..

Comment: They would be different years because they represent a span of time.  The information the text is conveying is that something lasted from 12/1/2015 to 1/8/2016.  The text can be parsed during either year. If it's parsed on 12/16/2015, both dates, with have the year 2015; if it's parsed on 1/6/2016, both dates will have the year 2016. The dates are being parsed individually, they appear on the text as something like 12/1 - 1/8, but I need to store each of them individually, so I'm using a regex to grab each one.  As I do so, I want to get the value and convert it to a DateTime at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToDateTime` just uses `DateTime.Parse`. My understanding is that when interpreting MM/dd formats, it will always assume the current year.

In your scenario, it sounds like you will need to make some determination on how you want to handle this. For instance, you could test that if the latter date precedes the prior date, you add a year.

Comment: And I plan on handling that.  My problem lies in the fact that I want to create a method that is able to parse the text, get the string value of one date and convert it to a DateTime object to return for something else to manipulate and determine if the year is correct or incorrect.  I just want to be able to tell if the year was added so it's easier to determine whether it's correct or not.